# Vaadin websocket not upgrading in version 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

See error from console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8090/vaadinServlet/PUSH?v-uiId=0&v-csrfToken=27328352-6365-44a4-b980-1ca2d7a5bc1c&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.3.2.vaadin1-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

This is after upgrading to vaadin 8.0.0
Push annotation and manual enabling of Push do not seem to make a difference. It reverts to long polling.

My best guess is it is a version problem. You can see it mentions atmosphere 2.3.2 in the error, but vaadin-push 8.0.0 imports atmosphere 2.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my understanding vaadin does have two atmosphere products integrated within vaadin-push, both forked by vaadin. One for the server side (https://github.com/vaadin/atmosphere) and one for the client side (https://github.com/vaadin/atmosphere-javascript). I assume that they do not need to be in sync. E.g. I saw that `atmosphere-samples-2.4.2` has been released using `atmosphere-2.4.2` and `atmosphere-javascript-2.3.0`.

There's also an issue https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8734, which states about the problem with vaadin-push through websocket (and also the version question). Hopefully they take care of this soon.

Comment: Comment in [8734](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8734#issuecomment-285482070) solved my issue. Very happy to see that it wasn't opened till after I posted the question! :)